# Why is there no Gemara on Avos?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna

Why is there no Gemara for Pirkei Avot? I can hear why Bavli has no Zeraim, and Yerushalmi has no Kodashim. But Pirkei Avos should have the most Gemara of all!

Comment: Avot d'Rabbi Nathan is the "unofficial" Gemara.  It is part of the "minor tractates" of the Talmud.

Comment: It doesn't actually make sense that there'd be no Kodashim in the Yerushalmi, since certain masechtot (namely Chullin) are still relevant without the Mikdash and were probably extant at one period